# Почему не работает функция exec в Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, exec

Почему когда `exec` в функции - он не работает, а вне функции всё нормально?
1)

```
def kaka(x):
    exec('y=' + str(x))
print(y)
```

2)

```
exec('y=3')
print(y)
```

1 не работает, 2 работает.
Объясните пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Функцию неплохо бы вызвать, а в `exec` явно передать аргумент `globals()`. `globals()` и без того передается в `exec` по умолчанию, но если его (и только его) указать явно, он передастся также и в качестве `locals`, который и используется в качестве пространства имен внутри функции.

```py
def kaka(x):
    exec('y=' + str(x), globals())

kaka('1 + 2')
print(y) # 3
```

Но рекомендую поискать альтернативы: использовать такие неуклюжие конструкции нет никакой необходимости.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!